# sympy - simplify expression with rational powers

Tags: sympy

The following code:

```
import sympy as sp
D, H, Vs = sp.symbols("D, H, V", real=True, positive=True)
x = sp.symbols("x", real=True, positive=True)

V = sp.pi * D**2 / 4 * H
V = V.subs(H, x) * D
D_expr = sp.solve(Vs - V, D)[0]
print(D_expr)
```

produces: `2**(2/3)*V**(1/3)/(pi**(1/3)*x**(1/3))`

I would like to simplify `D_expr`. In a perfect world I would like to get `(4 * V / (sp.pi * x))**(1/3)`

I tried the method `simplify()`, `powsimp()`, `powsimp(force=True)`: no luck at all! The expression remains the same. According to the [simplification tutorial](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#powers), my symbols should satisfy the necessary conditions for the simplification to occur. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numerical values are split out of radicals. Often this allows for better simplification when sums are involved, so `root(pi*x, 3)` will split into `pi**(1/3)*x**(1/3)`. But there is an option to return the root unevaluated...and if you want to force your factors under a cube root you can do:

```
>>> root(D_expr**3, 3, evaluate=0)
(4*V/(pi*x))**(1/3)
```